# Xamarin.Forms Android Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when trying to publish my Android app to the store.  I am able to push the same build to a device and emulator fine.  The build throws no errors when running, building, or archiving.  IOS builds archive and upload fine.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should Archive the project first.
[image: How to archive your android project]

Ensure your build configuration is in Release

What archiving does is to generate a signed release build of your project.
You can then proceed to publish the archived apk file from the following steps.

On Windows
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play/?tabs=vswin

On Mac
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play/?tabs=vsmac

Comment: Dara, thank you for the quick reply.  I am using VS on Mac.  I always follow the follow the following procedure prior to publishing:  Clean Build, Build All, Archive for Publishing, Sign and Publish.  So, the project is always archived prior to trying to publish.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have my Mac with me right now. If by the time I get it back, this is not answered, I should be able to help.

Comment: Another thing you could do is maybe use Visual Studio App Center to automate your deployment to Google Play (I do not have the step by step way of this but you can check out https://appcenter.ms to get started)

Comment: Ad-Hoc distribution seems to be working.  I can use that for now, but the uploading to google play's various channels like alpha and beta still does not work.

Comment: If ad-hoc works. Then I guess, you will need to digitally sign the apk with the Google API Keys.

Check this link out if it helps
https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com/2016/09/publish-your-android-app-to-google-play.html

Comment: I also found this link

https://blog.xamarin.com/android-archiving-and-publishing-made-easy/

Not sure for Mac right now. I have always published from Windows.